# Surveymonkey: Get all responses from a single day on a single transaction

Tags: surveymonkey

Is there a way to get ALL the responses for a single day **in one transaction** for a specific survey? on the API doc, I know there is the `/surveys/{id}/responses/bulk` option, and even I can send the `start_created_at` variable.

But I think that the API response has a max number of records/data it can send, it that case, what could the solution be? Paging through the results?

I'm using the .net API, found at [this site](https://www.simple-talk.com/blogs/new-net-library-for-accessing-the-survey-monkey-api/), but I can build my own wrapper if necessary.

Reference link to API doc: [/Surveys/SURVEY_ID/responses/bulk](https://api.surveymonkey.net/v3/docs?api_key=3yr7n6m8sjwvm48x8nhxej52#collectors-id-responses-bulk)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you're right the `/surveys/{id}/responses/bulk` endpoint is what you're looking for, and you can use the `start_created_at` and `end_created_at` to filter data to a date range.

The SurveyMonkey API doesn't allow a full dump of all your data, it will always be paginated. By default it'll paginate 50 at a time, but you can change that by using the `per_page` GET parameter.

That max `per_page` varies by endpoint, for responses BULK it is 100. So you'll have to fetch 100 at a time, looping through the pages to get all your data.

One alternative is to use [webhooks](https://developer.surveymonkey.com/api/v3/#webhooks) and set up a subscriber, that way you can get new responses in real time and fetch them one by one. That way you can keep your data updated on your side as new responses come in, rather than running a script or endpoint to bulk dump all your data. But this depends on your use case, if you're building something like an export feature, then you'll have to go through the paginated route.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Does the API has way of getting how many pages are in total? Or do I have to cycle through 'n' amount of pages until I get an empty set of responses -possibly meaning the end of the result set-

Comment: Yes there's a links header that shows next/prev/first/last page. That might also be in the body. Also the total number of responses should also be in the body so you can use that to calculate the number of pages.